# Expected Value of Exponential Function of Stochastic Process: $E[e^{X_t}]$

Tags: stochastic-processes, expected-value

I am still getting used to expectations and stochastic processes. Supposed we have a stochastic process defined by
$$dX_t = \mu(t,X_t)dt+\sigma(t,X_t)dW_t$$
where $W_t$ is a Wiener process. The simple thing I need to do is evaluate the following expression for some time $T>t$.
$$E_{t,x}[e^{X_T}]$$
Would I be correct in assuming the following logic?
$$E_{t,x}[e^{X_T}]=e^{E_{t,x}[X_T]}$$
Which then we can use Itô's Lemma to find $E_{t,x}[X_T]$. First we define $f(t,x)=x$. Now we have the stochastic differential. Here we use the facts that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}=0$ and $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}=0$
$$df(t,X_t)=\mu(t,X_t)dt+\sigma(t,X_t)dW_t$$
Now we integrate
$$\int_t^T df(t,X_t)=\int_t^T\mu(t,X_t)dt+\int_t^T\sigma(t,X_t)dW_t$$
Which implies this (the expected value of the $dW_t$ integral is zero).
$$f(T,X_T)=f(t,X_t)+\int_t^T\mu(t,X_t)dt$$
Finally we take expectation.
$$E_{t,x}[f(T,X_T)]=E_{t,x}[X_T]=f(t,X_t)+ \int_t^T E_{t,x}[\mu(t,X_t)]dt$$
So then this leaves me with the final representation of the expectation that I am looking for.

$$E_{t,x}[e^{X_T}]=e^{E_{t,x}[X_T]}=e^{f(t,X_t)+ \int_t^T E_{t,x}[\mu(t,X_t)]dt}$$

I guess then we just hope that the $\mu$ function is easy enough to analyze. This just still doesn't feel so comfortable to me, I was wondering if I'm doing this right or if I'm missing something here.

Thanks.

Comment: In general, $E[e^Z] \ne e^{E[Z]}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments above, it is not correct to assume that $\mathbb{E}[e^X]=e^{\mathbb{E}[X]}$.

The easiest counterexample is Normal vs. Lognormal distribution. If $X\sim N(\mu,\sigma)$, then $Y:=e^X$ is Lognormal by definition (i.e. see [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution) of Lognormal distribution).

The expected value of $Y$ is $\mathbb{E}[e^{X}]=e^{\mu+0.5\sigma^2}\neq e^{\mu}=e^{\mathbb{E}[X]}$.

You can either take the above as a "fact" that arises from the definition of Lognormally distributed random variable (i.e. you can memorize what the mean of a Lognormally distributed random variable looks like), or we can derive it by deriving the distribution of $Y$ from scratch:

$$F_Y(y)=\mathbb{P}(Y\leq y)=\mathbb{P}(e^{X}\leq y)=\mathbb{P}(X\leq ln(y))=\int_{-\infty}^{ln(y)}f_X(h)dh$$

Now:

$$f_Y(y):=\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left(F_Y(y)\right)=\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left(\mathbb{P}(X\leq ln(y))\right)=\frac{\partial}{\partial ln(y)}\left(\int_{-\infty}^{ln(y)}f_X(h)dh\right)\frac{\partial ln(y)}{\partial y}=\\=f_X(ln(y))\frac{1}{y}=\\=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{\frac{-(ln(y)-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}\frac{1}{y}$$

Taking the expectation:

$$\mathbb{E}[Y]:=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left(y f_Y(y)\right)dy=\\=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{\frac{-(ln(y)-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}\right)dy$$

Taking the substitution $y=e^h$, we get:

$$\mathbb{E}[Y]=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{\frac{-(h-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}\right)e^hdh$$

Now focusing on the exponents:

$$exp\left\{\frac{-(h-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}\right\}exp\left\{h\right\}=exp\left\{\frac{-h^2+2\mu h -\mu^2}{2\sigma^2}\right\}exp\left\{\frac{2\sigma^2h}{2 \sigma^2}\right\}=\\=exp\left\{\frac{-h^2+2h(\mu+\sigma^2) - (\mu+\sigma^2)^2 + (\mu+\sigma^2)^2 -\mu^2}{2\sigma^2}\right\}=\\=exp\left\{\frac{-(h-(\mu+\sigma^2))^2}{2\sigma^2}\right\}exp\left\{\frac{(\mu+\sigma^2)^2 -\mu^2}{2\sigma^2}\right\}=\\=exp\left\{\frac{-(h-(\mu+\sigma^2))^2}{2\sigma^2}\right\}exp\left\{\mu + 0.5\sigma^2\right\}$$

Plugging this back into the integral, we get:

$$\mathbb{E}[Y]=exp\left\{\mu + 0.5\sigma^2\right\}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{\frac{-(h-(\mu+\sigma^2))^2}{2\sigma^2}}\right)dh=\\=exp\left\{\mu + 0.5\sigma^2\right\}$$

Because the expression in the integral is the PDF of a Normally distributed random variable (with mean $\mu+\sigma^2$): which integrates to 1.

**Now to your problem**:

$$X_t=X_0+\int_{h=0}^{h=t}\mu(X_h,h)dh+\int_{h=0}^{h=t}\sigma(X_h,h)dW_h$$

If $\mu(X_h,h)=\mu X_h$ with $\mu$ being a constant and $\sigma(X_h,h)=\sigma X_h$ with $\sigma$ being a constant, then $X_t$ is Geometric Brownian Motion, which has the well known solution:

$$X_t=X_0exp\left\{\mu t -0.5 \sigma^2 t + \sigma W_t\right\}$$

From the above, we can see directly that $X_t$ is log-normally distributed. So that:

$\mathbb{E}[X_t]=X_0e^{\mu t}$

If you want to take the conditional expectation $\mathbb{E}_t[X_T]=\mathbb{E}[X_T|\mathcal{F}_t]$, then:

$$\mathbb{E}[X_T|\mathcal{F}_t]=\mathbb{E}\left[X_t exp\left\{\mu (T-t) -0.5 \sigma^2 (T-t) + \sigma W(T-t)\right\}\right]=\\=X_te^{\mu (T-t)}$$

**Edit**: if we cannot assume that the process is GBM (and therefore know its distribution), but we have to stick with the general $\mu(X_t,t)$ and $\sigma(X_t,t)$ functions (that, we must assume, are at least square-integrable, for $X_t$ to be an Ito Process), we can apply Ito's lemma as follows:

Ito's Lemma states that any twice differentiable function $F()$ of $X_t$ and $t$ follows the process:

$$F(X_t,t)= F(X_0,t_0) + \int_{h=0}^{h=t}\left(\frac{\partial F}{\partial t}+\frac{\partial F}{\partial X}\mu(X_h,h)+\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial X^2}\sigma(X_h,h)^2\right)dh + \int_{h=0}^{h=t}\left(\frac{\partial F}{\partial X}\sigma(X_h,h)\right)dW_h $$

We can apply the above formula to $e^{X_t}$ to get:

$$e^{X_t}=e^{X_0}+\int_{h=0}^{h=t}\left(0+e^{X_h}\mu(X_h,h)+\frac{1}{2}e^{X_h}\sigma(X_h,h)^2\right)dh + \int_{h=0}^{h=t}\left(e^{X_h}\sigma(X_h,h)\right)dW_h$$

Now we could attempt to take an expectation of the above: you are correct in your question to say that the expectation will "kill" the Ito Integral (because of the martingale property of the Ito integral, its expectation is equal to zero), but unless we know what the functions $\sigma(X_h,h)$ and $\mu(X_h,h)$ actually are, we won't be able to get any proper answer anyway, because we won't be able to simplify the expectation over the Riemann integral.

Comment: This is a great answer, although in your last section, "Now to your problem", I actually do not have a geometric brownian motion and it seems that you're coming up with an expression for the expectation of the GBM. I actually just need to evaluate $E[e^{X_T}]$, as you did in the first part. However your method relies on some math that I am not familiar with, like taking derivatives of probabilities. Something I'm still not getting though. You write, $E[e^{X_T}]=e^{\mu + 0.5\sigma^2}$, but this no longer depends on time. I would expect in general for $E[e^{X_5}] \ne E[e^{X_{10}}]$ for example.

Comment: $\mathbb{P}(X<a)$ is just the CDF of random variable $X$, which in turn is an integral $\int_{h=-\infty}^{h=a}f_X(h)dh$. So taking a derivative of "probability" in this case is just taking a derivative of an integral with respect to the upper integral limit: this is a "well-known" problem, in that the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus gives the result:

$$\frac{ \partial }{ \partial a}\int_{h=-infty}^{h=a}f_X(h)dh=f_X(a)$$

Comment: you're right, it is basic and exactly the kind of thing i need to be learning.

Comment: Regarding your question on the expectation not depending on time: expectation is just an operator that works the same way on time-dependent or time-invariant random variables. The way to think about it is that at each point in time, the variable $X_t$ will have a "constant" PDF, where $\mu$ (and all other parameters) are just multiplied by a "constant" $t$. All else works the same way.

Comment: Also I think $\mu$ and $\sigma$ are actually functions? I'm sorry things just aren't quite matching up for me. So in my question $X_T$ is defined by the stochastic process which is in general terms with functions $\mu(t,X_t)$ and $\sigma(t,X_t)$. It looks like you are just assuming $X_t$ is a normally distributed R.V., which doesn't seem like it has to be the case in my example? The course I am taking isn't using probability theory, they are using stochastic calculus with focus on Itô's lemma. Now after thinking more, I think the way the expect to answer is apply the lemma to $f(t,x) = e^x$.

Comment: @jeffery_the_wind: I edited my answer to show how Ito's lemma can be applied to $e^{X_t}$. The bottom line is that unless you know exactly what the functions $\mu(X_t,t)$ and $\sigma(X_t,t)$ actually are, you won't be able to simplify the expression and get any proper answer with regard to taking the expectation. Pls trust me on this, I have been dealing with Ito's lemma for over 10 years now in my professional career: you must know the precise form of the functions $\sigma(X_t,t)$ and $\mu(X_t,t)$ to get anywhere...

Comment: Thanks so much for taking the time here. I totally agree with you. In different exercises we actually do have the explicit form of these functions. So with my question here I was asking to me sure I'm understanding the general process for solving this type of question. It is great to get your insight. Also brings up a great point why we aren't studying any probability theory in this course that is always dealing with expectations, variances, etc!

Comment: Even if you know $\mu$ and $\sigma$, say both are equal to 1, and if you take an expectation of that last line you have, you still end up having to take the expectation of $e^{X_t}$ inside that expression. It is puzzling me.